# Project facet Dynamic Web Module 4.0 is not supported by this server

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

When, in **Spring Tool Suite**, I try to run my project with **Weblogic 12** I get this error:
**Project facet Dynamic Web Module 4.0 is not supported by this server**

1. Inside `org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml` I turned `<installed facet="jst.web" version="4.0"/>` into `<installed facet="jst.web" version="3.1"/>` but after doing **maven->update project** the version came back to 4.
2. I tried also to change the version here, but I get the error: **Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 3.1**
   [image]
3. I even tried to uncheck Dynamic Web Module (as suggested in another post) but I get the error: **Dynamic Web Module 4.0 cannot be uninstalled**

Does anybody know how to solde the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just recently had the same problem. The Dynamic Web Module is set by Maven according to your version of **javax.servlet-api**. Since Spring Boot 2.1.x imports Servlet-API version 4.0, Maven changes the project facet to match it.

Set Spring Boot's version to 2.0.8 or newer, which uses Servlet-API 3.1, and you'll be able to deploy your app to Weblogic 12c via Eclipse.