# Eclipse and Java Configuration to deploy on weblogic 12C local server not work

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, weblogic12c

I have configured and running a weblogic12C server (12.2.1.4.0) on my computer, and I am working with eclipe, where I have a spring boot application with java 1.8.

I need to configure ecplipse to deploy and debug on my local weblogic server.

The problem is that when trying to create the server in Eclipse and indicate what the server will be, its domain and the WAR to deploy, the wizzard says "The server does not support version 4.0 of the J2EE Web module specification."

**The strange thing is that my client has a 12C weblogic server (12.2.1.3.0) and I can deploy there without problems via console (ip: 7001 / console).**

Any ideas? Will it be a problem with the domain configuration?
Grateful for the answers !!

Some images speak more than a thousand words:

> **Configuration server weblogic wizzard**
> [image: Configuration server weblogic wizzard]

> **Selecting the domain**
> [image: Selecting the domain]

> **Indicating that it is a local domain**
> [image: Indicating that it is a local domain]

> **When trying to move the resource, the wizard tells me that it is not compatible**
> [image: When trying to move the resource, the wizard tells me that it is not compatible]

> **Checking the domain settings, I don't see anything wrong**
> [image: Checking the domain settings, I don't see anything wrong]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this document

https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/weblogic-server/12.2.1.4/wbapp/basics.html#GUID-62B6050D-6DD3-4028-B863-4CD0B5692E7F

> WebLogic Server fully supports HTTP servlets as defined in the **Servlet 3.1 specification** at http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=340. HTTP servlets form an integral part of the Java EE standard.

It looks like your Eclipse installation is trying to use Java EE version 4, which is not supported by Oracle Weblogic 12.2.1.*

Furthermore, I have found the below post, which I think could be useful to fix your issue.

[Project facet Dynamic Web Module 4.0 is not supported by this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54233669/project-facet-dynamic-web-module-4-0-is-not-supported-by-this-server)

That post explains the issue with Servlet-API version 4.0 and how to configure your IDE to use the version supported by Oracle Weblogic 12.2.1.*